# node restify oauth2 CORS -- 'No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: node.js, angularjs, restify

In my learning application, I'm using https://github.com/domenic/restify-oauth2 library to implement OAuth2. Here is code snippet in server.js file. I've modified /token endpoint to /api/v1/user/login'.

```
server.use(restify.CORS());
server.use(restify.fullResponse());
server.use(restify.authorizationParser());
server.use(restify.bodyParser({ mapParams: false }));
restifyOAuth2.ropc(server, { tokenEndpoint: "/api/v1/user/login", hooks: hooks });
```

While calling this API from angular.js it shows

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8090/api/v1/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

please help me out

Comment: I've not used restify, however, is there any part of the API that will allow you to add the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Comment: Yes, but restify.CORS() is already taking care of that.